# Using an IV as a DV

Tags: experiment-design, psychology

I am doing my thesis, and in my study design (a simulated negotiation) participants could choose from different messages (i.e., their negotiation strategy). The strategy variable is categorical (FR or IR) and therefore can be coded as binary (1,0) as it was for logistic regression exploring it as the outcome variable. Strategy was therefore a DV, as we were exploring how two different conditions impacted the way that participants chose their strategies.
HOWEVER.
My other DV was the subjective assessments of the negotiation which were made at the END of the experiment.
I am now wondering, how can I validly explore whether the negotiation strategy had a positive or negative relationship to the subjective assessments?
I am aware that using an single variable as both IV and DV is not ideal, but it seems incomplete to not look at this relationship.
Is there a way to do this? Perhaps the study design allows it? If so, does anybody have a reference I can look at?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of "IV" and "DV" are always relative to a particular research question. It's common for a variable to be an IV in one research question and a DV in the other, either across different studies or even in  the same study. Here you clearly have two separate research questions

RQ1: How do various (randomly assigned?) conditions (IVs) impact the subject's choice of strategy (DV)?

RQ2: How does the respondent's choice of strategy (IV) impact their assessment of the negotiation (DV)?

Those are both totally fine research questions, but they probably require different methods to answer.

For example, if the treatment variable in RQ1 was randomly assigned (which it kind of sounds like it was, given the description), then you don't need to do anything else aside from running a bivariate comparison and a significance test of some kind - the random assignment removes the possibility of the relationship being biased by other confounding variables.

But for RQ2 the IV (choice of strategy) was NOT randomly assigned. So a correlation between choice of strategy and subjective assessment might just be due to some confounding variable (like personality type) that causes people to both choose certain strategies and dislike negotiations. So you would have to think about if there is some way (regression analysis? matching? instrumental variables?) that could help you identify whether choice of strategy actually *causes* a change in subjective assessment. It might be that, given the way the data were collected and the control variables available it's just not possible to do this convincingly. That is, the experimental design was explicitly designed to answer RQ1, but wasn't well set up to answer RQ2. You will have to figure that out yourself.

You could also think of this in terms of structural equation modeling or path analysis, which explicitly allows DVs in one model to be IVs in another. But mathematically that isn't much different from just doing one regression analysis, and then doing the other.

So in short: It's fine to have multiple RQs where the DV of one is an IV of the other. But you need to test each RQ separately, and some RQs are easier or harder to robustly test in a given dataset.

Comment: Hi, thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I decided to do a mediation model using lavaan, essentially that negotiation strategy mediates the relationship between the condition (randomised) and subjective assessment. Such that, people will achieve lower subjective assessments when they are in the difficult negotiation condition, and this likely mediated by the fact that I reasoned that (a) this was my prediction and (2)

Comment: (2) I reasoned that this allows me to also get direct effect regressions without necessarily testing negotiation strategy as a DV.  Not to say that this strategy was the direct CAUSE of the subjective assessment, but if there is indeed a correlation, whether that be confounding variable, or the strategy itself, or those two things combined, warrants further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you assigned participants into two (?) conditions prior to giving them the strategy choice. And you assumed condition would affect strategy choice. And probably both condition and strategy may affect final assessment?

Maybe a structural equation model in which condition predicts strategy choice and both condition and strategy choice predict final assessment? This way you'd get everything in the same model, which is often considered desirable.

To be honest, I (not a statistician, but often deal with data relatively similar to yours) don't see anything wrong with running 2 models, one predicting strategy choice from condition and another predicting final assessment from condition, strategy choice, and perhaps their interaction if that might be of interest, as long as you report everything you did openly and in detail (I might be wrong here, curious to hear if that is so).